# Can emit keys have optional array params at the start of Array?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I am trying to design a couchdb map function which we can use for analytics, Our map function looks like this.

```
function (doc) {
    var t;
    var year;
    var date;
    var month;

    var hours, minutes, seconds, milliSeconds;
    if (doc.time && doc.zone && doc.user && doc.companyCode) {
        t = new Date(Date.parse(doc.time));
        year = t.getFullYear();
        month = t.getMonth() + 1;
        date = t.getDate();


        milliSeconds = t.getMilliseconds();
        //We emit this in the same sequence for group level queries.
        emit([doc.companyCode, doc.zone, doc.user, doc.eventtype, year, month, date], 1);
    }

}
```

I am using group level and it is working great.

What I wanted to know is - can i keep the zone optional in this or the user optional
Here are some of the queries i would like to ask this map/reduce.

1)What are all the events for a company, zone and a user in 2014. - this is possible now by keeping some of the time params optional.

2) Can we ask the same query what are the events for a particular year? I want to find out events for a companycode in year 2014.I want to make zone and user optional.

3) What are the advantages vs disadvantages to keep these indexes separate. Or should I ? :)

Answer (score 2):

To get your results you want range queries.

> 1)What are all the events for a company, zone and a user in 2014. - this is possible now by keeping some of the time params optional.

`?startkey=["company","zone","user","event",2014]&endkey=["company", "zone", "user", "event", 2014,{},{}]`

and this will give you the all the events for a company, zone and user in 2014.

> Can we ask the same query what are the events for a particular year? I want to find out events for a companycode in year 2014.I want to make zone and user optional.

Sure here goes

`?startkey=["company",null,null,null,2014]&endkey=["company", {}, {}, {}, 2014,{},{}]`

and this should give you the events for a company code and year 2014

> 3) What are the advantages vs disadvantages to keep these indexes separate. Or should I ? :)

Well this is a tough one to answer.The only thing I can say here is your index should answer  specific questions that you have. For instance based upon the questions you asked for the index above I would say that you have designed good indexes and there is no need to split them.

**So then what is a bad index?**

By the same token a bad index is the one which is unspecific. It tries to answer many questions and does not do well at any of them. For instance there is no point in splitting your design into

1. a company and date index
2. a zone and date index
3. a user and date index

and then aggregate the result after querying all three of them by yourself. Individually all three indexes are useless to you (assumption) but only when you assemble the result you get something meaningful. So in this case your single index approach is much better.

But I suppose you wanted to know more about performance implications. Multiple indexes mean that there will be more disk space used. If you have split your indexes across design documents you can even achieve a  degree of parallelism since each design document will be executed as a separate process. But unless that index answers a question that you want to be answered don't create it.

A small suggestion. I stumbled upon this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170659/couchdb-querying-and-filtering-by-three-indexed-keys) by @JasonSmith in which he gives some good advice on how to position your emitted keys. I think you can improve your emit structure a bit there.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed message. I will implement and mark it as an answer after.